# Check file name for range of characters

Tags: applescript

Is there a way to tell Applescript to locate a file where the file name would match this type of criteria:

```
set foundFile to file whose name starts with
```

***[character 0-9]*** followed by ***[character 0-9]*** followed by ***underscore***

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do it with a Finder whose clause statement. However grep has regular expression capabilities so try this...

```
set theFolder to choose folder
set foundFileNames to paragraphs of (do shell script "ls " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFolder & " | grep '^[0-9][0-9]_'")
set firstFoundFile to (theFolder as text) & item 1 of foundFileNames
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a handler that does this with all Applescript and no shell script.

```
-- get your folder however and feed the folder to the handler getMatchingFiles(*your folder*)

on getMatchingFiles(theFolder)
    tell application "Finder"
        set theFiles to every file of theFolder
        set allDigits to "0123456789"
        set matchingFiles to {}
        repeat with aFile in theFiles
            set fileName to the name of aFile
            if ((the first character of fileName is in allDigits) and (the second character of fileName is in allDigits) and (the third character of fileName is "_")) then copy aFile to the end of matchingFiles
        end repeat
    end tell
    return matchingFiles
end getMatchingFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

[regulus6633's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29525728/45375) is promising, but there's no need to resort to resort to external utilities `ls` and `grep`; the shell's own pathname expansion (globbing) is sufficient, using pattern `[0-9][0-9]_*`:

```applescript
# Pick a folder.
set targetFolder to choose folder

# Get matching files.
# `shopt -s nullglob` instructs the shell to return an empty string, if no files match.
set foundFiles to paragraphs of (do shell script "shopt -s nullglob; printf '%s
' " & quoted form of POSIX path of targetFolder & "[0-9][0-9]_*")

# Extract the 1st matching file.
set foundFile to item 1 of foundFiles
```